# Java sorting a String array and return the distinct Item

Tags: java, arrays, distinct-values

I have given the two arrays

```
array 1 :  a, b, c, d
array 2 :  a, b, c
```

I have used the

```
ArrayList<String> combine =  new ArrayList<String> ()
```

and all the elements in `array 1` and `array 2`

By sorting, I have found

```
a , a , b , b , c , c , d
```

Would you please tell me how to compare the elements in these two arrays and return the distinct items (d for example)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
ArrayList<String> charsA = new ArrayList<>();
charsA.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b", "c", "d"));
ArrayList<String> charsB = new ArrayList<>();
charsB.addAll(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

charsA.removeAll(charsB);
System.out.println(charsA);
```

prints

```
[d]
```

Obviously use a different list if you don't want any of the two original to be affected.

The `removeAll(Collection)` method

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with Arrays then you have to loop over both the arrays and compare values one by one. If you want to do it with ArraysLists then you can build your logic around `contains()` and `remove()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list1.add("a");
    list1.add("b");
    list1.add("c");
    list1.add("d");

    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    list2.add("a");
    list2.add("b");
    list2.add("c");

    List<String> distinctList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String string : list1) {
        if (!list2.contains(string)) {
            distinctList.add(string);
        }
    }
```